# AlamofireObjectMapper how to map object?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

This is the reponse which i got from api

```
{
Message = "email verification link has been sent to your email. please verify your account.";
Result =     {
    "V002_vendors_type" = "<null>";
    "V003_pharmacy" =         (
    );
    "V010_subscription" = "<null>";
    "attempt_date" = "<null>";
    created = "2016-04-27T12:26:04.5809108+00:00";
    email = "i9@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = jack;
    id = 10180;
    "is_lock" = 0;
    "last_name" = "<null>";
    mobile = 9999999999;
    password = e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e;
    "profile_Image" = "<null>";
    status = PV;
    subscription = 1;
    updated = "2016-04-27T12:26:04.5809108+00:00";
    "vendor_type_id" = 1;
};
Status = 1;}
```

now i am mapping this response by alamofireObjectMapper

here is my code

```
func pharmacySignUp()
        {
            let url = "http://\(basicURL)vendor_signup"
            let param :[String : AnyObject] =
                [
                    "email"      : txtemail.text!,
                    "password"   : txtpassword.text!,
                    "mobile"     : txtmobile.text!,
                    "first_name" : txtname.text!
              ]

            Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON).responseObject { (response:Response<signupVarificationCode, NSError>) in
                print(response.result.value)
                let signupVarificationCode = response.result.value
                print(signupVarificationCode)
                print(signupVarificationCode!.Message)
                print(signupVarificationCode?.Status)
                print(signupVarificationCode?.result)

                if let threedayForecast = signupVarificationCode?.result {


                    for ResultNew in threedayForecast {
                        print(ResultNew)

                    }
                }

            }
```

and these are my class in which i am saving values

```
class signupVarificationCode: Mappable {
var Message : String?
var Status : String?
var result:[String:AnyObject]?



required init?(_ map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    Message <- map["Message"]
    Status <- map["Status"]
    result <- map["Result"]
}

}





class Resultnew: Mappable 
{

var lastName : String?
var isLock : String?
var mobile : String?
var id: String?

var attemptDate : String?
var Created : String?
var Updated : String?
var Subscription: String?

var vendor_type : String?
var profileimage : String?
var pharmacy : String?
var vsbuscription : String?
var email: String?


var status : String?
var vendor_typeId : String?
var FirstName : String?
var Password: String?

required init?(_ map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    lastName <- map["last_name"]
    mobile <- map["mobile"]
    id <- map["id"]

    isLock <- map["is_lock"]
    attemptDate <- map["attempt_date"]
    Created <- map["created"]

    Updated <- map["updated"]
    Subscription <- map["subscription"]
    vendor_type <- map["V002_vendors_type"]

    profileimage <- map["profile_Image"]
    pharmacy <- map["V003_pharmacy"]
    vsbuscription <- map["V010_subscription"]
    email <- map["email"]

    status <- map["status"]
    vendor_typeId <- map["vendor_type_id"]
    FirstName <- map["first_name"]

    Password <- map["password"]
}
}
```

Here i am getting values in my function as

```
for ResultNew in threedayForecast {
                        print(ResultNew)

                    }
```

but these vales are coming like this

```
("last_name", <null>)
("mobile", 123456)
("is_lock", 0)
("attempt_date", <null>)
("created", 2016-04-27T12:32:20.6046072+00:00)
("updated", 2016-04-27T12:32:20.6046072+00:00)
("subscription", 1)
("V002_vendors_type", <null>)
("profile_Image", <null>)
("V003_pharmacy", [])
("V010_subscription", <null>)
("email", i10@gmail.com)
("status", PV)
("vendor_type_id", 1)
("first_name", jack)
("id", 10182)
("password", e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e)
```

but i cannot access is like this
print(ResultNew.mobile)

so how acn i access perticular value which i want to access.like i want to only password among these so how can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified that the `result` should be a dictionary (`[String:AnyObject]`) so you got a dictionary. Try changing it to this :

```
var Message : String?
var Status : String?
var result:Resultnew? // <-- this line
```

Comment: Thanks @Losiowaty its worked for me. Thanks for help